# TYPO3 tags and image issue with EXT: News System KEY: news VER: 2.2.1

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

**Hi All**

I'm running:

EXT.KEY: news on TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID/EXTBASE.

I have 2 issue's/question.

## 1 - News Tag's disappear, when using "tag list" in plugin.

I have added a "tag list" as element on my TYPO3 page, and its working fine, my problem is when i add another news plugin on another page, it's showing all the tag's from the two news plugin setup and I dont what to do that, so if i go to "Startingpoint" in Settings/plugin for the "Tag List" news-element and set it to the folder I save my newslist1 in, then all the tag's are disappeared, how can I set the "Tag list" so it's only show the tag's thats in the news from the folder "Newslist1"?

I have done this "startingpoint" with the list show and its working fine, if at news page 1 it show the news from folder "newslist1" and if on news page 2 it shows only the news/items from folder "portfolio".

## 2 - more images for a news.

Is it possible to add some image for the news text, so i have 2-3 images in the site, like when u add a normal text/image element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to issue 2**

You can enable the use of normal content elements in News. The switch to activate that feature is in the Extension Manager configuration of News. You then have the possibility to add any content element to a News record.

By default the content elements are rendered before the normal news content, see here:
https://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Extensions/news.git/blob/HEAD:/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html#l67

Of course you can change to order if you copy the template and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Ok so if I do this, then i leave the normale news TEXT field empty and click the Content elements and add a.. "Text" or "Text & Images" element, and write in that, or do i need to write something in the main/normal news text field, and will the new text/text & images element text be printet with the normal bodytext ?

Comment: Thx. Do U or other have an answer for 1, whats the reason is why the Tag's disappear, when i add a startingpoint for the tag list, i select the same folder as with the newslist and the newslist is working fine, its not showing news/items from the 2. folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Its beter add you plugin width ts, like

   ```
   lib.newstags = USER
   lib.newstags{
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
       extensionName = News
       pluginName = Pi1
       switchableControllerActions {
           Tag {
                1 = list
           }
       }
       settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
       settings {
           listPid = 73 # here you tagse source page/folder
      }
   }
   ```
2. Its beter to use Type "Innernal link". You can select in item edit form. Than you can add any page like contents element in your news item.